# python - not quite figuring out re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace any expression including a single digit number plus a character by a single digit, a blank, and the character.

Example: '3f' should become '3 f'

I am doing the following to make sure I know what is the regex I intend to replace.

```
import re

found = re.match(r'^[0-9][a-z]$', '3f')

if found:
    print 'ok'
```

The result is:

```
>> ok
```

However, when I do

```
found = re.sub(r'^[0-9][a-z]$',r'^[0-9] [a-z]$', '3f')
```

I get:

```
>>>> '^[0-9] [a-z]$'
```

instead of '3 f'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
found = re.sub(r'^([0-9])([a-z])$',r'\1 \2', '3f')
#                  ^^^^^  ^^^^^
#                    1      2
```

you need to specify with `r"\1"` for first match , `r"\2"` for second match, etc

you specify matches with capture groups `()` in your regex

Comment: thanks a lot Joran. When I include '\1' and '\2' in the second argument of re.sub it means that I will repeat whatever expression I have in the first argument? I noticed that re.sub(r'^([0-9])([a-z])$',r'\1whatever\2', '3f') results in '3whateverf'. Is that the overall logic? thanx again.

Comment: `\1` is the first match and `\2` is the second match, as determined by your match captures (indicated by parentheses).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than rely specifically on string matching, another possibility is to manipulate the matched groups directly with a function instead:

```
found = re.sub(r'^([0-9])([a-z]$)',lambda matchobj: matchobj.group(1) + ' ' + matchobj.group(2), '3f')
```

Comment: this is a good answer for more complicated substitutions ... its probably overkill here :P (good answer though)

Comment: True, but worth it if other people come straight to this question with complicated substitutions. Plus, I personally find it easier to read. :)